# Are there any strange edge-cases where a partially constructed object can be accessed in c#?

Tags: c#, constructor

Is there any situation in which a type with a perfectly self-contained constructor* could be accessed by code outside of the constructor before the constructor has completed? That is, is a self-contained constructor guaranteed to be run before the object can be used in any fashion?

*A constructor that does not pass the `this` parameter to any methods, including implicitly passing it by calling any methods on itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> is a self-contained constructor guaranteed to be run before the object can be used in any fashion?

No it is not guaranteed. See this link

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatterservices.getuninitializedobject.aspx

So your object can be initiated without calling your constructor.

> Because the new instance of the object is initialized to zero and no constructors are run, the object might not represent a state that is regarded as valid by that object.

You can reproduce it by:

```
var demo = (DemoClass)System.Runtime.Serialization
                      .FormatterServices.GetSafeUninitializedObject(typeof(DemoClass));
Console.WriteLine("PROP=" + demo.Prop);
```

---

```
public class DemoClass
{
    public int Prop = 5;
    public DemoClass()
    {
        Prop = 6;
    }
}
```

Output will be **`0`**, not 5 or 6...